# Retain trailing 's' for table in Postgraphile

Tags: postgraphile

Is there a way to disable the 'remove-the-plural-s' feature in Postgraphile?

I have a table `OS` in my database and am using the very awesome [Postgraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/) library to create a GraphQL interface for free. Everything is great, but Postgraphile is truncating my table name, thinking it is plural. So I get `allOs` instead of `allOses` and `createO`, `updateO`, etc...

I tried:

- Adding an underscore after the table name, and then it just retains the entire thing with an underscore.
- Adding an underscore (`O_S`) and then the plural has capital-s `allOS` but the singular is `O_`
- A [smart comment](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/smart-comments/#renaming) specifying `E'@name os'` but it still drops the `s`
- A smart comment specifying `E'@name oss'` which then pluralizes correctly `allOsses` (haha) and keeps both for the singular `oss`

PS in case you see this Benjie/other contributors, your documentation is incredible and the library will save me months of work.

Comment: For the record, I can think of only 'species' and 'OS' as possible singular nous ending with a single 's'... so maybe the pragmatic solution is to rename to 'operating_system' rather than expecting some special workaround. sadface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This change is performed by PostGraphile's inflector; however it doesn't always get it right (e.g. in this case) but fortunately it's possible to override it with a small plugin.

In this case, it's probably best to add specific exceptions to the `pluralize` and `singularize` functions; you can do this using [makeAddInflectorsPlugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-add-inflectors-plugin/) from our [inflection system](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/inflection/). Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument so that the system knows you're deliberately overwriting the inflectors.

```js
const { makeAddInflectorsPlugin } = require('graphile-utils');

module.exports = makeAddInflectorsPlugin(oldInflectors => ({
  pluralize(str) {
    if (str.match(/^os$/i)) {
      return str + 'ses';
    }
    return oldInflectors.pluralize(str);
  },
  singularize(str) {
    if (str.match(/^osses$/i) {
      return str.substr(0, 2);
    }
    return oldInflectors.singularize(str);
  }
}), true);
```

I'm glad you're enjoying PostGraphile